# Verify Tx Signature

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, lucid, cardano-multiplatform-lib

Say I created a multi-sig transaction and I am now gathering signatures using the Cardano-multiplatform-library.

How can I check that the signature is correct for my transaction body, and the signers pub-key ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

In case you find your self coming here to find the answer, you can create an instance of TransactionWitnessSet, using the witness you got from the wallet api.

```
const witness  =  C.TransactionWitnessSet.from_bytes(hexToBytes(signature))
```

You can then derive the publicKey of the signer, and use the publicKey method `verify()` to verify against your transaction.

```
Const validSignature =   witness.vkeys().get(0).vkey().public_key().verify(tx, witness.vkeys().get(0).signature()))
```